# How to select one record from table with multiple condition at same field?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table like this:

```
---------------------
| id | user | group |
---------------------
|  0 |  103 |    27 |
|  1 |  107 |    31 |
|  2 |  103 |    32 |
|  3 |  112 |    31 |
|  4 |  135 |    64 |
|  5 |  135 |    66 |
---------------------
```

This is table of groups and users and as you can see there can be records with same user and different groups. How can I select, for example, the records with same user and two groups - 27 and 32? It would be the same user.

So, how can I do this?

**EDIT:** To show expected result I wrote a sample:

```
SELECT user FROM table ... (maybe WHERE group = 27 AND group = 32)
```

-- gives user id 103

**EDIT 2:** ***I've found it!***

Here is query that perfectly working for me:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE `user` in
(
    SELECT `user` FROM table
    WHERE `group` = <needed_group_1>
)
AND `group` = <needed_group_2>
```

Thank's to all for help, I've found all your answers useful!

Comment: can you update your question to show what is your expected result?

Answer (score 2):

To get all data that has more than 1 group do

```
select * from your_table
where `user` in
(
  select `user`
  from your_table
  group by `user`
  having count(distinct `group`) >= 2
)
```

To get the data that has 2 specific groups do

```
select * from your_table
where `user` in
(
  select `user`
  from your_table
  group by `user`
  having sum(`group` in (27,32)) >= 2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user
FROM theTable
GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(group) = 2
```

This might also help you:

```
SELECT
    user,
    COUNT(*) as cnt,
    GROUP_CONCAT(group)
FROM theTable
GROUP BY user
```

And if you want to grab all records that match your condition:

```
SELECT theTable.*
FROM theTable
JOIN (
    SELECT user
    FROM theTable
    GROUP BY user
    HAVING COUNT(group) = 2
) AS UsersWithTwoGroups USING(user)
```

Comment: You should not select columns that you are not grouping by. It works for MySQL but the result is not predictable.

Comment: @juergen d Absolutely. I got mixed with column names (`id` vs. `user`). Updated. (on second thought, this table is not a `User` table, hopefully).

Answer (score 1):

you almost got it

try this

```
  SELECT user FROM table1 WHERE id in ( select `group` = 27 AND `group` = 32
                                      from table1)
  group by user
```

**NOTE.** : `group` is reserved mysql keyword so escape it by backticks

this will give :

```
 USER
 103
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36486/5)

Comment: how it not working, what error u got , or what have you tried.

Comment: look the demo , you have changed something or you used it wrong , anyway if you done something else share it and we will see why its not working with you.

Comment: I do it right as you specified. Maybe it's specifics of my system.. Anyway, I've found solution that works for me :)